# Websphere MQ PowerShell Library reporting "MQRC_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED" on any Cmdlet call

Tags: powershell, ibm-mq

I am currently running a local IBM MQ Server, version 7.5 on my Windows machine. I need to automate administrative tasks such as creating queues, topics, and subscriptions. For this, I've planned to use [Websphere MQ - Windows PowerShell Library](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24017698), as it has Cmdlets supporting all these functions.

The problem I am currently facing is that no matter what of the provided Cmdlets I execute, such as *Get-WMQQueue*, I get an exception for the IBM MQ error "MQRC_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED". I have provided a screenshot that demonstrates this.[image: Error]

I haven't been able to find all that much information about what the potential problem could be, other than the IBM page for the error: [MQRC_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q043270_.htm)

However, OPMODE does not seem to be the cause of the issue here.

Does anyone know what else could cause this issue? I can through the IBM MQ Explorer that the powershell process connects correctly through a Server-connection channel that I have created, but from there it seems like no commands will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have downloaded the latest version and the powershell window should be run with Administrator privileges. Can you run the command with the debug option set in the environment.
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
It will provide some more information.If that doesn't help send an email to the people listed in the first page of the mo74.pdf